# Why doesn't this CSS code work?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

```
li.widget ul li {
    margin-bottom: 0.714em;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

on Rootmyandroid.org

I want to set the background color of right side bar sub widget links to black so I have given `#000000` color. And I have set the thing (for which I want to add black background) to green color on hover.

When I use firebug to inspect CSS, it does not show the `background-color: #000000;`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Post more code please or throw it all into a jsfiddle, standard. Thank you.

Comment: In addition, keep in mind the hierarchy of CSS. An external stylesheet is over-ruled by CSS in the head of the document; which is, in turn, over-ruled by CSS in the style attribute of the element. Basically the last style encountered by the browser overrides any previously specified, and otherwise-conflicting, rules (unless the keyword of !important is used).

Answer (score 1):

In your custom.css you have a line:

```
//side bar edit start color wala
```

this is not a valid comment and so the rule

```
li.widget ul li {
    margin-bottom: 0.714em;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

is ignored

comments on styles sheets are always opened `/*` and closed `*/`:

```
/*side bar edit start color wala*/
```

Comment: that was so dumb of me ! really thanx !

Answer (score 0):

Set the background-color in your layout.css at line number 227

```
li.widget ul li {
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 0.714em;
}
```

Comment: how to go directly to line 227 ?? :0

Comment: @user2126750 That depends on your IDE of course, we can't tell you that.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to change the color of the LINKS, you have to add "a" like so:

```
li.widget ul li a { ... }

or 

li.widget a { ... }
```

Comment: im trying to edit the background of the area where the links are placed in the sidebar. plese tell me how to.